# Splitting and Hardcoding worksheets containing pivot tables

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to using VBA code. I have a workbook with manually created tables as well as pivot tables. For each worksheet in this book, I want to hard-code the data into a new workbook and save it as the name of the worksheet that is being hard-coded. I have the code below. It is saving each workbook properly, but the contents of the workbook are not correct. It is hard-coding the contents of the first worksheet in my original workbook every time. I've tried to set the next ActiveSheet at the end of the code but it fails. Did I mention I am not a programmer? Please help!

```
Sub Splitbook()

Dim path As String
Dim dt As String
path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\SLF\ "
Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & path, vbNormalFocus)

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs path & ws.Name, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: OK. What is your question? What's wrong with your code? Why do you call explorer app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the code looping through the sheets of your workbook so you do not need to copy from the `ActiveSheet` but from the `ws` worksheet variable.

You also do not need to use `Select` to get data copied.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim newBook As Workbook
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.UsedRange.Copy
    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add
    With newBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
    newBook.SaveAs Path & ws.Name, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    newBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next ws
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. This solved another issue I was having where I couldn't use Set/With on pivot tables using .Cells().Formula = .Cells().Value. Thanks for your help! Much appreciated